# "Can’t read from the source file or disk" when I try to copy files from my C:\ to another drive

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive

When I try to drag & drop files from my C:\ onto my Mac hard drive (I use MacDrive for HFS support), Windows reports:

```
Interrupted Action

Can’t read from the source file or disk
```

Specs:

- Windows 8 Professional x64
- MacDrive 9.0.3.35
- Mac OS X 10.8.2
- MacBook Pro 2009

Comment: I assume you've checked the source drive already for errors?

Comment: What filesystem is your Windows 8 drive running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 8 uses new hardware drivers, which appear to MacDrive as if the whole computer is new, requiring reactivation.

Upon reactivating MacDrive with my same old serial number, drag & drop and editing Mac drive functionality was restored.