# "Can’t read from the source file or disk" error when copying particular files

Tags: windows, hard-drive

Using Windows 10, I am trying to back up several thousand photos from my computer’s internal HDD to an external HDD.

For three files I get the message "Can’t read from the source file or disk". If I click Skip for each of those files, I can copy all other files successfully. The three photos that don’t work were all taken on the same day and in fact within a minute of each other. The photos open OK in Windows and in all other respects seem to be normal.

I’ve tried the following:

- Restarting the computer
- Running CHKDSK on the external HDD
- Running CHKDSK on the computer's internal HDD
- Renaming the file

I don’t think the error relates to the external HDD because it recurs if I use a different external HDD, and the error also recurs if I try to copy it from one part of my internal HDD to another.

There is [a somewhat similar question on this site](https://superuser.com/questions/499307/can-t-read-from-the-source-file-or-disk-when-i-try-to-copy-files-from-my-c-t), but the answer here must be different and can’t involve MacDrive, and furthermore in my case only 3 files (out of several thousand I am trying to transfer) are affected rather than all files.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the directory entry block or journal has an issue.  That's one of very few things that 3 files share in common.

1. Try a DOS prompt with SFC c:/scannow, it will try to find any flaws with the whole disk's file system (including more than CHKDSK does)
2. Try to move the file to another folder like c:\temp (create if necessary, but don't write a lot of stuff to the troublesome drive, it might get worse).  Then try to copy.
3. Try to boot-time optimize (defrag) the MFT and journal files (See below, and I use Defraggler, used to use DisKeeper.)
4. Is an AV program hanging on to the photos for some reason (byte pattern?)
5. Try a different (viewer?) program to open / save / zip the files to another volume?
6. Do a SMART scan of the drive, if it is capable.  If you have one bad block, you might have more.  If many, get a new drive.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67112327/deleting-recreating-ntfs-journals-or-how-to-properly-run-the-fsutil-usn-com

I've had this happen a few times, each OS and version have their particularities.  Also make sure (view in thumbnail view) the target files are intact.  I'm over 80K files, and keep copies in different places (painful).